# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'streamlit' when loading into my Heroku app

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, python-3.8, streamlit

**I'm using Python 3.8.5**
I've made an app in Python that uses Streamlit, and when I deploy it using Heroku, I get this error when loading into the page. [image]

My `requirements.txt` file contains all the packages and their versions including Streamlit.

```
matplotlib==3.3.3
pandas==1.1.5
numpy==1.19.5
streamlit==0.74.1
tensorflow-cpu==2.4.0
seaborn==0.11.1
Pillow==8.1.0
```

My `setup.sh` file:

```sh
mkdir -p ~/.streamlit/

echo "\
[server]\n\
headless = true\n\
port = $PORT\n\
enableCORS = false\n\
\n\
" > ~/.streamlit/config.toml
```

My `Procfile`:

```
web: sh setup.sh && streamlit run site.py
```

I've tried several different versions of Streamlit but I always get the same the same error.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the name of your site from `site.py` to something else, for example `my_site.py`. Streamlit tries to import a module called `site` but your file is named `site.py`.